# Chrome debugger tool only works in localhost

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I was trying to debug some javascript for my website, these javascript is callable from Chrome Debugger Tool when I test it in localhost, but when I deploy to the live site, I couldn't call these methods any more, any idea?

Comment: are you using minifed js files at live site? are you appending timestamp to the js files at live site?

Comment: Not minified, but I append timestamp to the .js file at live site. But some other dev in the same team is able to call these methods thou.

Comment: you cant debug in chrome when you append timestamp, as it changes. I faced the same issue, I used Internet explorer 10 to debug. Check in IE once.

Comment: We need more detail about what you tried and what the results were. When you say you "couldn't call those methods anymore", what happened? What did you type in the devtools console, and what was the result?

Comment: e.g. there is a me object in my website that stores user information, the others can access the me object in devtools, but when I typed in me, it says undefined.

Comment: Are you sure all the resources are getting loaded? Check the network tab to see if your firewall is blocking any resource from being loaded or there is a resource that isn't loaded via https.

Comment: Hi @Chirag64, all are working fine. Everyone load from the same website, you can try it here www.co-oprating.com

Comment: So what's the name of this object that you're trying to access and which JS file has it? I saw you mentioned an object named 'me' in your previous comment, but I couldn't find any such object in any of the JS files.